# Consulta Compleja Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Quiero sacar en una tabla cuantas personas pertenecen a un departamento y su jefe de departamento, sino hay personas, mostrará 0, y sino hay jefe departamento asignado, cualquier valor ("no hay",0, me da igual)

En esta select saco el número de personas asociadas a los departamentos, poniendo 0 sino hay ninguno:

```
SELECT d.Nombre_Depart as Departamento, Count(u.nombre) as total 
from departamentos d left join usuarios u on d.Nombre_Depart=u.Departamento
GROUP BY d.Nombre_Depart order by total
```

En esta select los jefes del departamento.

```
 Select departamento,Nombre,Apellidos
 from usuarios,departamentos,union_pers_rols
 where usuarios.Departamento=departamentos.Nombre_Depart
 and union_pers_rols.Id_usuario=usuarios.Correo 
 and usuarios.Departamento=departamentos.Nombre_Depart
 and union_pers_rols.Id_rol='Jefe Departamento'
```

El problema es que no sé combinar las 2 Selects.

En la Tabla Usuarios tengo los campos : Nombre,Correo,Departamento

En la Tabla Departamento tengo los campos : Nombre_Depart

Usuarios tira la fk a Departamento

En la tabla Rol tengo los campos: tipo_rol.

En la tabla Union_pers_rol los campos : ID_usuario , Id_rol

Union_pers_rol tira la fk de ID_usuario a usuarios.correo y de Id_rol a la tabla rol.tipo_rol

Comment: Está un poco raro el diseño de las tablas. En particular, el model parece permitir varios jefes por departamento.

Comment: Si, es verdad, tampoco sé como solucionar eso...Me di cuenta esta tarde...

Comment: ¿Quieres corregir el modelo?

Comment: Lo tengo hecho a papel, el lunes lo llevo a que me lo revisen, de momento necesito ayuda con la consulta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La consulta sería algo como:

```
select d.nombre_depart,
       coalesce(max(jefe.nombre), 'no hay') as nombre_jefe,
       count(u.nombre) as total
  from departamentos d
  left join usuarios u
    on u.departamento = d.nombre_depart
  left join (
    select u.departamento, u.nombre
      from usuarios u
      join union_pers_rols upr
        on upr.id_usuario = u.correo
       and upr.id_rol = 'Jefe Departamento'
  ) jefe
   on jefe.departamento = d.nombre_depart
 group by d.nombre_depart
 order by total
```

Pero como ya te distes cuenta, el diseño tiene ciertos problemas. Entre otras cosas, es posible tener mas de un jefe por departamento. Si eso sucediera, la consulta te puede devolver datos erróneos.

En realidad, lo mejor sería corregir ese problema moviendo la información de jefe directamente en la tabla `departamentos`.

Además, es siempre mejor establecer las relaciones entre las tablas usando ids numérticos que no pueden cambiar. Usar nombres o correos para establecer relaciones es peligroso porque pueden cambiar.

En realidad, un diseño mas correcto se parecería a lo siguiente:

**Tabla `usuarios`**

- `usuario_id` (PK)
- `departamento_id` (FK hacia `departamentos(departamento_id)`)
- `nombre`
- `correo`

**Tabla `departamentos`**

- `departamento_id` (PK)
- `jefe_id` (FK hacia `usuarios(usuario_id)`)
- `nombre`

Entonces la consulta sería:

```
select d.nombre as nombre_departamento,
       coalesce(jefe.nombre, 'no hay') as nombre_jefe,
       count(u.usuario_id) as total
  from departamentos d
  left join usuarios jefe
    on jefe.usuario_id = d.jefe_id
  left join usuarios u
    on u.departamento_id = d.departamento_id
 group by d.departamento_id, jefe.usuario_id
 order by total
```

Comment: Perfectísimo muchas gracias, la verdad es que no sabía esas cosas, mañana a primera hora, restructuro todo,muchas gracias máquina !